# Julia wrapper for Cuba and fork on Windows?

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

According to its developer, the Cuba library (for numerical integration) will not run(?) on a Windows machine since the OS is missing the function fork(2).

> Windows users: Cuba 3 and up uses fork(2) to parallelize the execution threads. This POSIX function is not part of the Windows API, however, and is furthermore used in an essential way such that it cannot be worked around simply with CreateProcess etc. The only feasible emulation seems to be available through Cygwin.

See [http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/][1].

Since Cuba.jl is just a wrapper for the Cuba library, does this mean that Windows users must install Cygwin in order to use this Julia package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install Cygwin to use `Cuba.jl`, a normal Windows system is sufficient. The package is tested on [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/giordano/cuba-jl/history) without any problem